# Помогите разобратся с шоткодом на wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Пишу плагин, который в зависимости от роли пользователя будет выводить (admin или author) или не выводить форму car_form.php! Помогите разобраться почему не работает?

car_form.php:

```
<form name="test" method="post" action="input1.php">
    <p><b>Name : </b><br>
        <input type="text" size="40">
    </p>
    <p>Description : <Br>
        <textarea name="comment" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить">
        <input type="reset" value="Очистить"></p>
</form>
```

functions.php:

```
add_shortcode('hsws_car_list', 'hsws_car_list_func1');

function hsws_car_list_func1($atts) {

    add_action('init', function() {

        $user = get_user_by('slug', 'admin' || 'author');

        if ($user == 'admin' || 'author' ) {

            reguire "car_form.php";
        } else {
            echo 'Вы не автор и не админ!';
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что когда дело доходит до выполнения шорткода на странице, событие init давно позади. Вам это событие совсем не нужно.

```
add_shortcode('hsws_car_list', 'hsws_car_list_func1');
function hsws_car_list_func1($atts) {
    $user = get_user_by('slug', 'admin' || 'author');
    if ($user == 'admin' || 'author' ) {
        ob_start();
        reguire "car_form.php";
        return ob_get_clean();
    } else {
        return 'Вы не автор и не админ!';
    }
}
```

И да, функция шорткода не должна выдавать форму на экран или использовать echo. Она должен вернуть строку. Для этого форма обернута в буферизацию php.